# Update View + Controller + Database after removed/added fields in domain

Tags: grails

I am working on grails project, I have made a domain and generating `views` and `controller` by using command. After it generate it all, it works but After that I want to remove one field from the `domain`.

Before Removed

```
package com.liftoff

class Person {

    String studentID
    String firstName
    String middleName
    String lastName
    String year
    boolean isMarried

    static constraints = {
        studentID ()
        firstName ()
        middleName ()
        lastName ()
        year ()
        isMarried ()
    }
}
```

After removed one field from `domain`, here I need it automatically update all `view` and `controller` and `database`.

```
package com.liftoff

class Person {

    String studentID
    String firstName
    String middleName
    String lastName
    String year

    static constraints = {
        studentID ()
        firstName ()
        middleName ()
        lastName ()
        year ()
    }
}
```

Any way to do this in Grails ??

Comment: You should run generate-all command once again, after domain classes update.

Comment: @emilan Won't it remove my all database entries and whatever changes I made it in controller ?

Comment: Actually if you changed your domain class, you should update your db by running application with `create` mode or you should do it manually with `SQL` statements. Also `generate-all` will reset all your changes in views and controllers.

Comment: @emilan Any way without resetting these all ?

Comment: The only way is to do it manually. Remove manually part of code that uses removed domain property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, once you have generated the views/controllers and other artifacts you must manually maintain any changes you make to your Domain classes.

However, if you are in the process of prototyping and aren't customizing the artifacts quite yet you may benefit from [dynamic scaffolding](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/scaffolding.html). Instead of generating your controllers and views, create your controller and then mark it as scaffolded. For example:

```
class BookController {
    static scaffold = true
}
```

In addition setting your `dbCreate` in your `DataSource.groovy` to 'update' will keep your schema in your database in sync with your changes to your Domain classes.

Answer (score 0):

As an update to the [answer given](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22855477/4420271), **Grails v3.0+** no longer supports this way of defining dynamic scaffolding. Instead, as described in the [Grails documentary](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/scaffolding.html), assign the domain class to the scaffold property (instead of assigning `true`).

For example:

```
class PersonController {
    static scaffold = Person
}
```